# How to fetch the XPATH of an initialized IWebElement in c#

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, appium, winappdriver

I am using WinappDriver/Appium to automate an windows application project.

I have initialized an Parent WindowsElement using Xpath.

Now once the Element is initialized i want to get the XPATH of the (Parent) Element which was used so that i can get the Child elements using the Parent XPATH.

```
session = UiaWindowDriver.CreateSession(new Uri(WindowsApplicationDriverUrl), uiaDriverOptions); //WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>
var Window = session.GetWindow("//Window[@Name=\"Sample Application\"]"); //Returns me an WindowsElement
```

Now as i got the Window (i.e. Parent Control) i want to get the child elements of the Parent Control.

Any help is appreciated.

Many Thanks !!!

Comment: Please refer https://medium.com/@licanhua/inspecting-ui-elements-for-winappdriver-automation-using-appium-desktop-8f178b2d0d6c

Answer (score 0):

Why create it as a Window? You can just create that as a WindowsElement like...

```
WindowsElement parentWindow = session.FindElementByXPath("//Window[@Name=\"Sample Application\"]");
```

THEN this will allow you to look for additional elements isolated to this window like so..

```
WindowsElement someElement = parentWindow.FindElementByXPath("...");
```

In some cases it may throw an error related to casting, you can resolve that like so...

```
WindowsElement someElement = (WindowsElement)parentWindow.FindElementByXPath("...");
```

I am almost certain this will work in your case.